# UILabel isn't Displaying at Center of View - Xcode Playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have the following code running on Xcode Playground. However, even though I specify that the label is centered at the center of the view, it doesn't appear there.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
        label.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / 2, y: view.frame.height / 2)
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        view.addSubview(label)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = TestViewController()
```

[image]

Comment: try  `label.textAlignment = center`.

Comment: It is working fine for me. Also instead of calculating the center, you can just use `label.center = view.center`

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the suggestion, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view` frame is not finalized when `viewDidLoad` is triggered, you need to set the frame of the label inside the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as this method is being invoked when view bound was finalized.

**Try**

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.label.center = self.view.center
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The view controller's view's frame is not final in `viewDidLoad`.

You either need to set the label's autoresizingMask or apply constraints to keep it in the center.

And since you made the label wider than the text, you also need to set the label's `textAlignment` to `center`.

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
label.center = view.center
label.text = "Hello World!"
label.textColor = .black
label.textAlignment = .center // or call label.sizeToFit()
label.autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, ]
view.addSubview(label)
```